# Entering Sweden with an EU ID card

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, sweden, eu-citizens

On the 3rd of August I tried to drive to Sweden with a truck, using also a ferry from Grenå to Varberg. At the entry to the port I had to show my passport, as showing just my Slovenian EU ID card was out of question.

Is this correct, according to EU/Schengen rules?

Comment: Just curios - how many years ago did it happen?

Comment: Do you mean from _Grenå_ to Varberg? That's an internal Schengen crossing. Were the persons you interacted with Swedish police or Stena Line employees?

Comment: @Neusse Not necessarily. The event might be from tomorrow. The truck is probably a time machine.

Comment: It was two days ago and the staff was the one of Stena line.A quite sturdy lady,she didn't flinch when I told her she's breaking EU rules.BTW,similar behaviour was shown to me by Skatteverket officials in Karlstad when I came with necessary paperwork for Personnummer,but rhen I just complied.

Comment: @BucoNovosel You can use your ID Card to get a Personnummer, however to get an ID Card from Skatteverket (to be used as an ID with your Personnummer on it), a passport is required - non-Swedish national ID cards, even from Finland, are **not** accepted

Answer (score 4):

They were amateurs - absolutely no need to even bring a passport. If that ever happens again and you don't have a passport, just ask to speak to their supervisor - they usually know their stuff.

As a verified EU citizen, **they have no right to refuse you entry**, other than if you're a security/health threat

Comment: As I suppose you know, the letter of the law lists security as one of three grounds under which those enjoying freedom of movement may be denied entry, the other two being public health and public policy.

Comment: @phoog Yes, added health, but don't know what public policy actually means

Comment: I believe it's the reason one would use to deny entry to, for example, a war criminal.  I imagine there are other uses for that reason but I'm not sure how (or whether) it has been invoked in the past.

Comment: Maybe they didn't like the cargo:30 tons of Danish cheese.You don't bring that stuff in Sweden without a passport,do you?